# QueryDSL and search in list of element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, querydsl

I have a user that have an organization and a list of customer. The two properties are in mutual exclusion. Customer have a reference to organization.
When i search for user i need all the user that are in my organization, all the user that are in a customer that have my organization plus any parameter present in search

this is my code

```
 public PaginationResponse getUsers(UserAndOrderFilter userFilter, User currentUser) throws Exception {
    if(currentUser == null) throw new Exception("No authenticated user");
    QUser user = QUser.user;
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    if(Util.isRoleManager(currentUser)){
        BooleanBuilder orBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
        orBuilder.or(user.organization.eq(currentUser.getOrganization()));
        orBuilder.or(user.customer.any().organization.id.eq(currentUser.getOrganization().getId()));
        builder.and(orBuilder);
    }
    if(Util.stringHaveValue(userFilter.getUsername())){
        builder.and(user.username.eq(userFilter.getUsername()));
    }
    if(Util.stringHaveValue(userFilter.getCompanyName())){
        builder.and(user.customer.any().name.equalsIgnoreCase(userFilter.getCompanyName()));
    }
    OrderSpecifier<?> sortOrder = null;
    switch (userFilter.getOrderField()){
        case "email":
            sortOrder = Objects.equals(userFilter.getOrder(), "asc") ? user.email.asc() : user.email.desc();
            break;
        default:
            sortOrder = Objects.equals(userFilter.getOrder(), "asc") ? user.id.asc() : user.id.desc();
            break;
    }



    FetchableQueryBase q = (FetchableQueryBase) (new JPAQuery(em)).from(user).where(builder).distinct().offset(userFilter.getPage()* userFilter.getPageSize()).limit(userFilter.getPageSize()).orderBy(sortOrder);
    FetchableQueryBase q1 = (FetchableQueryBase)(new JPAQuery(em)).from(user).where(builder).distinct();
    return new PaginationResponse(q1.fetchCount(), q.fetch());
}
```

and this is the query that hibernate write (i removed order and limit)

```
    select distinct u1_0.id,u1_0.active,u1_0.creation_date,u1_0.creation_user,u1_0.email,u1_0.organization_id,u1_0.password,u1_0.update_date,u1_0.update_user,u1_0.username 
from users u1_0 
where u1_0.organization_id=1 or exists(select 1 from user_in_company c1_0 join customer c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.company_id where c1_1.organization_id=1 and u1_0.id=c1_0.user_id)
```

My questions are:

- How can i search in internal list?
- How can i wrap  expression (like the parentesis in sql query)?